# differentiating dragging and selecting in Java's JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, draggable, mouseevent, jtextarea

My Java application has several `JTextAreas` that the user can move around. I achieve this by adding a mouse motion drag listener to it.

```
  public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    int deltaX = e.getXOnScreen() - screenX;
    int deltaY = e.getYOnScreen() - screenY;

    setLocation(myX + deltaX, myY + deltaY);
  }
```

I am having a problem differentiating when the user wants to select text within the `JTextArea` and when they want to drag it around. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I would use a modifier, for example *control*  `e.isControlDown()`, or another mouse button to drag the component.

Comment: This is probably the only method that isn't going to annoy your users to no end. Rocky's and StanislavL's methods will not let the user select the complete text by dragging the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to handle the first mouse down, check to see if text is selected.  If the mouse pointer is on the text then set it to a state to identify it as a drag.

Answer (score 1):

Use viewToModel() to obtain caret position of pressed point. Check whether the caret position is between getSelectionStart() and getSelectionEnd(). If it's in selected region start drag.